# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 null (Spring RestTemplate)

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm trying to send a GET request with RestTemplate. My code looks like:-

```
   RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
   headers.add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
   headers.add("_rToken", cookie.getValue());
   String url = getUrl(contextUrl);
   HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);
   ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
   try {
       response = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
   }
   catch(RestClientException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   return response;
```

On debugging, my URL looks good. What I have as entity is:-

```
body = null,
headers = <{Accept=[application/json], 
            user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36],
           _rToken=[2a6ac90f-1dfb-4df3-8d23-6d8d948fb9b5]}>
```

Since my get method doesn't take a parameter, body is supposed to be null. What am I doing wrong here?

Stack trace:

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 null     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:773)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:726)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:682)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:598)
>     at com.hm.ul.util.PlpUMCommunicator.get(PlpUMCommunicator.java:53)

Comment: `403 null` is not complaining your null body in the http request but the response body. Are you sure your url can be accessed by a browser?

Comment: Your authentication (token) is incorrect, so the server responds 403 forbidden.

Comment: `headers.add("_rToken", cookie.getValue());` can you post what is `cookie`?

Comment: cookie's value = "fd6ddefd-421a-4bdc-9b59-d85ecc1b8983"

Comment: IMHO, cookie is a name-value pair, and it can only be accessed from a HTTP request or HTTP Response. You should make sure that `cookie` is the right one: the one containing the right `token` in its value field.  According tho the stack trace, the value of your cookie is `2a6ac90f-1dfb-4df3-8d23-6d8d948fb9b5`

Comment: That was for the previous request. For the current request, the value of my cookie is the same one - "fd6ddefd-421a-4bdc-9b59-d85ecc1b8983"

Comment: What if you use the previous one? A token should be issued by the server and, should live for a certain time and should not be invalid within that time preriod.